# How do I install PHP Statistics extension in my Laravel Project?

Tags: php, laravel, php-extension

I want to invoke the [`stats_rand_gen_exponential()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-gen-exponential.php)  function but apparently to do so I need to install the Statistics extension.

How do I install extensions using Composer?

**UPDATE**

I cannot understand what could possibly be wrong.

[image]

Comment: That page you posted has a chapter [Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/stats.installation.php)

Comment: The problem is literally that the dll file you're looking for isn't there, and the installation docs indicate that a DLL for this isn't available. To use this on Windows you will need to follow the instructions to compile it from source. Or you could consider running it in a Linux environment, such as in a VM via something like Vagrant.

Comment: See my screenshot. The dll file _is_ there.

Answer (score 2):

PHP extensions can't be installed using Composer. You can *require* them, but all that does is tell Composer that they need them to run, so that they will fail explicitly when someone installs the dependencies for your package. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages for details.

There are a number of ways to install PHP extensions and the best will often depend on your platform. On Linux, there may be packages available for that extension via your package manager, and if so that's the easiest method. [PECL looks to be the recommended installation method for this extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/stats.installation.php), so that would be my second choice if it's not available via a package manager. Or if you're using phpbrew you can probably use `phpbrew ext install` to install the extension you need.